# Decoding UTF-8 Encoded Header

Tags: php, utf-8, email-headers

I'm using PHP imap to read emails out of an inbox. It extracts some information from headers. One of the headers looks like this:

X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?=

The original value of that encoded string is Eugen Babić.

When I try to decode that string using PHP, I can't get it quite right, the ć always comes back messed up.

I've tried imap_utf8, imap_mime_header_decode and a bunch of others I can't quite recall. They either don't return anything at all, or they mess up the ć as I mentioned before.

What is the correct way to decode this?

Comment: How is the accented c entered in your encoded string?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I'm not sure what you mean by 'entered in your encoded string'.

I didn't encode the string myself, I assume it was done by whatever sent the email.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, how was the accented c originally entered? According to wikipedia: the Unicode codepoint is U+0107 for ć. Was it entered using this code, was it entered using a Microsoft word shortcut (these are always treated badly by other programs), was it entered using a key on a Polish language keyboard?

Comment: Where is the string taken from? the character's HTML entity is &#264; so if it is from a HTML page, use this code instead of pasting the accented c character itself.

Comment: It's simply stored as its unicode value in a database. When the email is sent out the name is pulled from the database and put in the header. I'm not sure that's the issue though, because this same encoded string is in the subject header of the email, and gmail manages to decode it perfectly fine, I just can't do it with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're doing wrong: You're HTML (as generated by the PHP) is not UTF-8 encoded. So even though it's returning the accented c, the page isn't displaying it correctly.

To fix it, add this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Comment: Sending the charset in the Content-Type HTTP header is preferable to using a meta tag.

Answer (score 2):

`imap_utf8` and `imap_mime_header_decode` work just fine; there's also `iconv_mime_decode`:

```
php > echo imap_utf8('X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?='), "\n";
X-My-Custom-Header: Eugen Babić

php > list($k,$v) = imap_mime_header_decode('X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?=');
php > echo $v->text, "\n";
Eugen Babić

php > echo iconv_mime_decode('X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?=', 0, "utf8"), "\n";
X-My-Custom-Header: Eugen Babić
```

It seems that `imap_utf8` returns its output in NFD, so that the accent over the c may appear out of place in some settings.

Comment: I put together a small script on a server so you can see the output (I copy-pasted your exact examples): http://cameronsflash.com/misc/test.php as you can see, the accent over the c is wrong in every case :\

Comment: Looks good to me, in every case. One thing that you could do is specify the charset in Content-Type: `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8')`. Currently you have it set to text/html, which means the browser has to guess. Your browser must be guessing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The function mb_decode_mimeheader() solved the problem

```
            "fromName" => (isset($fromInfo->personal))
                ? mb_decode_mimeheader( $fromInfo->personal) : "",
```