# PHP Notice on imap messages

Tags: php, email, imap

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$mbox = imap_open("{serwer.uk:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "mail@serwer.uk", "veryhardpass");

if($mbox)
{
        $num = imap_num_msg($mbox);

        if($num>0) {
                ///print(imap_fetchheader($mbox, $num));
                ///print(imap_qprint(imap_body($mbox, $num)));
                echo imap_fetchheader($mbox, $num);
                echo imap_qprint(imap_body($mbox, $num));
                imap_setflag_full($mbox, "$num", "\\Seen");
                imap_mail_move($mbox, "$num", "Archive");
                imap_expunge($mbox);
        }

}
imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

And sometimes I got an error:

```
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Invalid quoted-printable sequence: ="000000000000312523056bfe743a"

--000000000000312523056bfe743a
Content-Type:  (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0
```

This string is the place when attachement begins. 
What is wrong with the script and how to write it properly?

Comment: You should check the header to see if the message is in quoted-printable format.

Comment: Could You propose an update?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092161/php-imap-get-body-and-make-plain-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa